# Can I use ATtiny48 as a board in Arduino?

Tags: hardware

I have seen people using ATtiny45 and other boards and there are hardware configurations files for them. Can we use ATtiny48 as a processor for Arduino?

If so where can I get a boards.txt file that supports it? Alternatively how can I write such a file?

Comment: @Gerben that is "MEGA48" ...